# Регулярные выражения: вырезать тег p и изменить ширину

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php, html

Всем привет! Помогите, пожалуйста, составить регулярку. Имеется примерно такой код.

```
<p><iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/3SEDJSYob_s" frameborder="0" height="350" width="425"></iframe></p>
```

Нужно вырезать `<p>` и изменять высоту и ширину на значения предустановленных переменных.

Comment: нет просто их вырезать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вырезать то без проблем

```
$width=1300;
$height=169;

preg_match_all('~(?<=<p>)<iframe.*</iframe>(?=</p>)~Uis',$htm,$arr);
$ifr=preg_replace('~(.*height=")[\d]+(" width=")[\d]+(")~i','$1%2$d$2%1$d$3',$arr[0][0]);
// если иной порядок параметров
$ifr=preg_replace('~(.*width=")[\d]+(" height=")[\d]+(")~i','$1%1$d$2%2$d$3',$ifr);
// меняем "высоту"/"ширину"
$ifr=sprintf($ifr,$width,$height);

echo $ifr; // тут iframe
```

не самый изящный код, зато удобный

принцип: вырезаем `<p>` заменяем значения width и height на описатели. Зачем? Полагаю html будет храниться в БД, поэтому обработанный html до `$ifr=sprintf($ifr,$width,$height);` сохраняем. А когда нужно вывести видео нужного размера вызываем `sprintf` с указанием нужной высоты и ширины

Comment: к примеру у меня на сайте будет несколько вариантов видео ,в превью выводиться мимнимальный размер 300x169 ,при переходе на страничку размер уже другой т.е больше. 
Значения будут храниться в переменных ,и вот вместо height="350" width="425" мы подставляем эти переменные

Comment: При чём тут тогда регулярки вообще? Воспользуйтесь любым шаблонизатором, или на худой конец свой напишите, куда проще жить будет. Да хоть на примитивном str_replace:

    $template = str_replace( '__PREVIEW_WIDTH__', '300', $template );